# How can I serve an existing html file through a View in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

I've a set of pre-generated html documentation files (provided via an external mechanism). These are fully standalone in their own right, but I'd like to integrate these files into an existing portal.

Ideally, I'd like the existing site to take care of the (common) layout, and simply embed the existing html into this layout. I've been trying to get it to work over the last few hours to no avail.

Problems I've encountered (no specific order):

- The pre-generated content already contains html/body/etc. tags (as mentioned, it is standalone documentation in its own right).
- Redirection is no use, as it bypasses the view mechanism, losing the common layout.

I'm not really sure how to proceed, as I seem to have exhausted my googling ability on this matter. I'd appreciate any tips or pointers on concepts or terminology surrounding what I'm trying to do - I'm happy to do the leg work investigation as required.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting your html files in the wwwroot folder and in the Startup.cs Configure method, add the line `app.UseStaticFiles();`

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't serve the layout. I've almost got it working with an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to static *.html use

```
var htmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"patch/to/your.html");
```

And then pass it to view and render by `@Html.Raw()` but i not reccomend this way. Better create partial view and then simply use by `@Html.Partial()` ([official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial))